# Obtain ListBox SelectedItem through ContextMenu with Multibinding in Windows.Resource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to use multibinding on a context menu stored in Window.Resources and I can't figure out how to get the SelectedItem of the ListBox I attach the menu to.

I think I need to use PlacementTarget, but can't get anything to work.  I tried using FindAncestor, but that didn't work.  I also tried getting the listbox by the ElementName to no avail.

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:IPViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:Int32 x:Key="Number">0</sys:Int32>
        <sys:Int32 x:Key="NumberLetter">1</sys:Int32>
        <sys:Int32 x:Key="NumberLetterNumber">2</sys:Int32>

        <local:CombineParams x:Key="CombineParams"/>

        <ContextMenu x:Key="DetailMenu">            
            <MenuItem Header = "Number">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>                    
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SwitchLabelMode}">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>                                
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CombineParams}">
                                    <!-- The next line is where I'm not sure what to write to get to the listbox -->
                                    <Binding Source="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}"/>                                  
                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource Number}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </MenuItem>
            ...
    </Window.Resources>

    ...
            <ListBox Name="IndexDetailsListBox"
                    ...
                     ContextMenu="{StaticResource DetailMenu}"
                     ...>

            </ListBox>
...    
</Window>
```

I can't get it to give back anything other than unset value.
I'm grateful for any help.  None of the other questions I found have the contextmenu in Window.Resources with MultiBinding which seems to be my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that you assign `RelativeSource`- object to the `Source` property of the `Binding` object. `RelativeSource`- object belongs to the `RelativeSource`-property.
So you get your `List` to the multi value converter:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CombineParams}">
    <Binding Path="PlacementTarget" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}"/>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource Number}"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  Thank you so much.  I'd upvote you but it won't let me under 15 reputation.